# failed to start dse solr node

Tags: search, solr, cassandra, datastax

I'm trying datastax enterprise 4.8.4 on ubuntu. Installation is OK following the instructions. I can start a cassandra node with the command `sudo service dse start`. Then I want to try restart as a solr node on the same machine. So I edit the `/etc/default/dse` and set `SOLR_ENABLED=1`. Now I tried to start cassandra again, it failed.

```
@ubuntu:~$ sudo service dse start
* Starting DSE daemon dse                                                                                 
DSE daemon starting with Solr enabled (edit /etc/default/dse to disable)
[ OK ]
@ubuntu:~$ sudo service dse status
* dse is running

@ubuntu:~$ sudo service dse status
* dse is not running
```

I checked the `/var/log/cassandra/system.log`. Here's the error message:

```
ERROR [main] 2016-01-28 16:44:02,767  CassandraDaemon.java:294 - Fatal exception during initialization   
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Cannot start 
node if snitch's data center (Solr) differs from previous data center 
(Cassandra). Please fix the snitch configuration, decommission and 
rebootstrap this node or use the flag -Dcassandra.ignore_dc=true.
```

The question is how could I fix it? or where do I add `-Dcassandra.ignore_dc=true`?

Comment: by editing `/etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra-rackdc.properties`, I managed to get dse running. But still don't know when it is changed by what command and how the dc and rack settings should be set.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of [2.1.13](https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/CASSANDRA-9474) you are not allowed to change the data center of an existing node. This is to protect users from making a mistake in production since changing data center (DC) names in a live system will result in downtime.

The DSE simple snitch assigns nodes to logical data centers based on workload type. I.E. solr nodes will be added to a solr DC, Cassandra nodes will be added to a Cassandra data center. If you change the workload type using DSE simple snitch you change the DC name which is not permitted by default.

If this is a test environment and you know what you're doing (you are willing to incur the breif downtime while all the nodes in your DC are changed to a new DC) you can submit the [following jvm flag in your cassandra-env.sh](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/NEWS.txt)

-Dcassandra.ignore_rack=true and/or

-Dcassandra.ignore_dc=true.

**make sure your topology after the DC / name change is still the same, otherwise replication can get messed up and you can end up with a lot of streaming + CPU utilization + io + stale reads **

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and actionable comment! On a serious note, this should work, what exactly are you seeing fail?

Comment: I resolved the problem, this command works for me: `sudo dse cassandra -Dcassandra.ignore_dc=true`

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps you can take to solve the problem -

**Error :** - CassandraDaemon.java:709 - Cannot start node if snitch's data center (Cassandra) differs from previous data center (SearchGraphAnalytics).

**Solution** : -

1. Change the network topology to `GossipingPropertyFileSnitch` from `SimpleSnitch` in *Cassandra.yaml* file , placed at */usr/share/dse/resource/cassandra/conf* ( if installed as no service)
2. Create a properties file with datacenter and rack information if not exists .

   - Path : */usr/share/dse/resource/cassandra/conf*
   - filename: *cassandra-rackdc.properties*

   And add the below entries -

   ```
   --indicate the rack and dc for this node dc=SearchGraphAnalytics // the previous name of your DC before upgrading rack=RAC1
   ```
3. If Gremlin server Error persists then run the graph using below parameters -

   This error may com when DataStax Enterprise was installed from a tarball or from the DataStax Installer with the No Services option.

   Start the dse using the below parameters : -

   ```
   /usr/share/dse$ bin/cassandra -g -s -k
   ```